# Can you still combo break an opponent's move with no life bar?

Tags: killer-instinct-2013

I'm watching several videos on YouTube regarding the latest edition of Killer Instinct and noticed that many Ultra combos are started when their opponent's life bar is near empty. I know that you can use Combo Breakers to interrupt a Combo midway (or a player can use a Shadow Cancel to interrupt a Combo Breaker).

Such as in this video (done without combo breakers, also careful this is a 30 minute video):

My question is: When a player's lifebar depletes, can they still perform Combo Breaker's or do the controls of the (soon-to-be) defeated player not respond when a player has no lifebar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no, once the lifebar depletes, that's it. Your input is no longer read. Just watch *any* video of gameplay where people combo break a lot, it all stops when they are defeated. Some players will use this to "show off" and do multiple ultras and combos... much like your video, but a tad less... long.

Comment: Can an opponent rage quit an online match mid combo?

Comment: they can quit the match before the game ends and it will interrupt. after the match ends and they leave the match won't interrupt.